# Internal name of column name in sharepoint automatically changed

Tags: sharepoint

I'm creating several columns in the list. The column name which starts with C replaces the name with_x0043_ for example, the actual column name which I create is "CHA016" but what SharePoint created is_x0043_HA016. Why does it automatically replacing C as_x0043_as internal name? Please help to identify this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I could also reproduce this on my end. I tried the actual name as "CH", "CHA" and "CHA0", and their internal names are "CH", "CHA" and "_x0043_HA0". I can't find any official documentation to explain this. To figure out this, you can open a service request in Microsoft 365 admin center to confirm it with Microsoft.